# How to test RPC port for accepting traffic

Tags: parity, testnets, kovan

I have a fully synced node running in my personal computer with kovan testnet. I want to test if my RPC port is accepting traffic or not. I am using parity as a system service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any call to methods from https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module should work for rpc.

For example requesting the current block number

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```